# Nielsen & Chuang Exercise 2.5 - Inner products of complex vectors

Tags: mathematics, nielsen-and-chuang

Reproduced from Exercise 2.5 of Nielsen & Chuang’s Quantum Computation and Quantum Information (10th Anniversary Edition):

> A function $(\cdot, \cdot)$ from $V × V$ to $C$ is an inner product if it satisfies the requirements:
>
> (1) $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is linear in the second argument,
>   $$
> \left(|v⟩,  \sum_iλ_i|w_i⟩\right) = \sum_i λ_i (|v⟩, |w_i⟩).
> $$
>
> (2) $(|v⟩,|w⟩)=(|w⟩,|v⟩)^∗$.
>
> (3) $(|v⟩, |v⟩) ≥ 0$ with equality if and only if $|v⟩ = 0$.
>
> For example, $C^n$ has an inner product defined by
>   $$
> ((y_1,...,y_n),(z_1,...,z_n)) ≡ \sum_i y_i^* z_i = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \ldots & y_n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ \vdots \\ z_n\end{bmatrix}.
> $$
>   **Verify that $(·, ·)$ just defined is an inner product on $C^n$.**

*Note: This question is part of a series attempting to provide worked solutions to the exercises provided in the above book.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just an exercise in linear algebra (though that isn’t entirely off topic) and also because the future of this series is in question